# Come to think of it/ now you mention it

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

These idiomatic phrases overlap. Both precede another comment about something just mentioned. An example of the first one is:-
The meeting is next Tuesday, which, come to think of it, is also the date of my doctor's appointmen.
And of the second:-
The weather's been a bit unpredictable lately. B: "Now you mention it, I hear there could be a blizzard next week."
Apart from obiter and quasi praeteriens, I can’t find a Latin equivalent. etenim is the nearest particle I could find but it fails to convey the exact sense of the English idiom.

Comment: Perhaps: *de quo quando quidem admonitus sum, …*, or: *quorum quoniam me admonuisti, …*?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! admoneo is spot on for this context, and quando quidem perhaps has more of a colloquial flavour than quoniam. Moreover, I think that in addition quandoquidem signifies realisation not just explanation i.e. it includes some sense of understanding the situation. A question: might de quo and quorum be ambiguous—‘about whom/ of whom’ or does the construction after admoneo [aliquem alicuius rei] preclude the alternative? But your translation of both of these idioms (including two other similar ones like ‘speaking of which/ talking of which) covers all the alternatives.